# Django: Accessing data in templates with FK

Tags: django-templates

I have my models:

```
class Volume(models.Model):
    volnumber = models.IntegerField('Volume Number', primary_key=True) 
    year = models.TextField()
    #...#

class Article(models.Model):
    volnumber = models.ForeignKey(Volume)
    title = models.TextField(blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    #...#
```

my view:

```
# Article detail
def article_detail(request, slug):
return render_to_response('article_detail.html', {
    'article': get_object_or_404(Article, slug=slug),
})
```

my template:

```
{{ article.volume.year }}. <strong class="title">{{ article.title }}</strong>.Journal Vol.{{ article.volnumber }}
```

The problem is I am not getting any output for the year (title and volnumber are fine). The syntax seems correct..what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
{{ article.volnumber.year }}
```

Since you're simply [following the relationship forward](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/queries/#forward), `article.volnumber` should give you a reference to the associated Volume object.

You're not seeing anything in your template because `article` does not have a `volume` attribute. The templating engine fails silently and nothing is printed.

---

Better yet, to make the references more intuitive you might want to consider renaming the attribute in your `Article` model from `volnumber` to simply `volume`.

```
class Article(models.Model):
    volume = models.ForeignKey(Volume)
    # ...
```

Using `article.volume.year` and `article.volume.volnumber` is, in my opinion, a lot more readable than `article.volnumber.volnumber`.